# Create table in a view odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo

How can I create a table in a page of notebook in my view? Do you know if that is even possible?

I need that in order to put a default values on my column "libellé" as the examples on my photo i want to give to each line of column "libellé" a default value 
 [exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiQIG.png)

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- formulaire view ghb -->
        <record id="sakr_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sakr.form</field> 
            <field name="model">sakr</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="charge" version="7.0"> 
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                    <field name="raisonsociale"/>
                                    <field name="matricule"/>
                                    <field name="datenaissance"/>
                            </group>
                            <group>
                                    <field name="adresse"/>
                                    <field name="nom"/>
                                    <field name="dateembauche"/>
                            </group> 
                            <group>
                                    <field name="affilie"/>
                                    <field name="cnss"/>
                                    <field name="fonction"/>
                                    <field name="datedepaie"/>

                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="Détails">
                                <group>
                                    <field name="salaire_id" nolabel="1">
                                        <tree  editable="top"> 
                                            <field name="libelle"/>
                                            <field name="base"/>
                                            <field name="taux"/>
                                            <field name="gains"/>
                                            <field name="retenues"/>
                                        </tree>
                                    </field> 

                                </group>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

this is my py file

```
class sakr(osv.osv):
    _name='sakr'
    _description='sakr assistance'

    _columns = {
        'datedepaie': fields.date('Date de paie'),
        'raisonsociale': fields.char('Raison sociale'),
        'adresse': fields.text('Adresse'),
        'affilie': fields.char('N° affilié CNSS'),
        'matricule': fields.char('N° Matricule'),
        'nom': fields.char('Nom et prénom'),
        'cnss': fields.char('N° CNSS'),
        'datenaissance': fields.date('Date de naissance'),
        'dateembauche': fields.date('Date embauche'),
        'fonction': fields.char('Fonction'),
        'salaire_id': fields.one2many('salaire', 'salaire_parent'),
    }

    _defaults = {


        'datedepaie': date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    }    

class salaire(osv.osv):
    _name='salaire'
    _columns = {
        'libelle': fields.char('Libellé'),
        'base': fields.float('Base'),
        'taux': fields.float('Taux'),
        'gains': fields.float('Gains'),
        'retenues': fields.float('Retenues'),
        'salaire_parent': fields.many2one('sakr'),
    }
```

Comment: Your code just seems fine. What is the problem here? To get default values, just use `_defaults` like in your model `sakr`

Comment: thank you for your answer @CZoellner in fact i need to give to each line a different value if i use defaults all the lines will have the same value

Comment: You can also write a method for default value computation. What is the logic behind the default values?